# Declare a specific address for a string in MPLAB XC8 Microchip compiler

Tags: c, compiler-construction, pic, microchip

With compiler C18 when I want to use a specific address for a string I use:

**In .C**

```
#pragma romdata idsoft
    const rom unsigned char _app_nfo[31]= {"V0.0 No        - 05/12/12"};
#pragma romdata
```

**in linker:**

```
CODEPAGE   NAME=idsoft     START=0x78E0         END=0x78FE
```

How can i do same with XC8?
I've try many things, but none of them are working.

**in XC8 linker parameter:**

```
-L-pappnfo=0x78E0
```

**In .C :**

```
unsigned char __section ("appnfo")  app_nfo[31];
```

It's not working.

Comment: Can you post links to the toolchain homepage (and ideally the linker manual)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have just to do this:

```
unsigned char _app_nfo[31] @ 0x78E0 = {"V0.0 No        - 05/12/12"};
```

See `5.5.4.2 ABSOLUTE OBJECTS IN PROGRAM MEMORY` in [MPLAB XC8 C Compiler User’s Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52053B.pdf)